# SQL update column values with substring value

Tags: mysql, sql

So my table is https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdGp6.jpg.
I want to update the **name** column so that it removes the *Telefon mobil* part(to look like the first row).

Answer (score 2):

Use [REPLACE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_replace.asp) function, to replace the specific substring with an alternate substring in the `name` field:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET name = REPLACE(name, 'Telefon mobil ', '');
```

Comment: Only suggestion is that you may want to replace the space after "mobil" as well, so that the text does not have a leading space. IE: `'Telefon mobil '`.

Comment: @Rtoyo ya just added that.